# UICollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated: doesn't work with iOS8

Tags: scroll, ios8, uicollectionview

I test an application on iOS8 which works well on iOS7. It seems that the function "scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:" doesn't work on iOS8.

This is my function which used it.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([collectionView isEqual:m_CollectionViewSequence])
        [m_CollectionViewSequence scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];
}
```